# How to create a Button's Template with ContentPresenter's content having distinct Foregrounds that can be changed by the Button's VisualState

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Let's say that I have a styled button with the content as follows:

```
<Button x:Name="exampleButton"
        Style="{StaticResource exampleButtonStyle}">
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="firstTextBlock"
               Text="{Binding firstText}" />
    <TextBlock Name="secondTextBlock"
               Text="{Binding secondtext}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

These TextBlocks bind to a ViewModel of a Page the ***exampleButton*** is declared in.

The ***exampleButtonStyle*** looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="exampleButtonStyle"
       TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    ...
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="rootGrid">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                ...
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="exampleButtonContentPresenter" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I want the ***firstTextBlock*** and the ***secondTextBlock*** to have two distinct Foreground brushes. Both of the brushes need to be changed to different colors (also distinct) when the ***exampleButton*** enters ***PointerOver*** VisualState.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the textblock directly in the button ControlTemplate .Then when trigger the "PointerOver",the foreground brush will change.The firstBlock from green to red and the secondBlock from green to orange.

**Update:**
If you want to bind your textblock's text to the viewmodel,first declare **DataContext**.

```
this.DataContext = ViewModel;
```

Or

```
<Page.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:ViewModel x:Name="viewModelInDataContext"/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

Then use **Binding** to bind the property to the textBlock.

```
<Style x:Key="exampleButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <!--Change the SolidColorBrush, ButtonBrush, to red when the
            Pointer is over the button.-->
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBrush" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red"  Duration="0"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBrush2" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Orange"  Duration="0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>

                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <StackPanel Height="100">
                                <TextBlock Name="firstTextBlock"
               Text="{Binding String1}" Height="50">
                                    <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="ButtonBrush" Color="Green"/>
                                    </TextBlock.Foreground>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Name="secondTextBlock"
               Text="{Binding String2}" Height="50">
                                    <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="ButtonBrush2" Color="Green"/>
                                    </TextBlock.Foreground>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
</Style>
```

Only need to bind the button style.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource exampleButtonStyle}" x:Name="exampleButton" Width="100" Height="300">
</Button>
```

Comment: But can I bind the TextBlocks' text to my ViewModel properties from the template then?